# Insert error when trying to save to core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm experiencing a problem when trying to save a new object to Core Data a second time after saving a previous object successfully the first time.

**The two relevant entities are Child and Nursing:**

```
class Child:NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var avatar:NSData!
    @NSManaged var birthdate:NSDate!
    @NSManaged var datecreated:NSDate!
    @NSManaged var datemodified:NSDate!
    @NSManaged var bloodtype:NSString!
    @NSManaged var eyecolor:String
    @NSManaged var firstname:String!
    @NSManaged var gender:String!
    @NSManaged var haircolor:String!
    @NSManaged var baths:NSSet!
}

class Nursing : NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var leftduration: Double
    @NSManaged var leftstarttime: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var mood: String
    @NSManaged var note: String
    @NSManaged var rightduration: Double
    @NSManaged var rightstarttime: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var spitup: Bool
    @NSManaged var child: Child
    @NSManaged var completed: Bool
    @NSManaged var leftstate: String
    @NSManaged var rightstate: String

}
```

There is a one to many relationship between Child and Nursing:
Child <-->> Nursing

**Here is the function that creates a new record and saves it to Core Data:**

```
func createNewNursingRecordWithSide(side: String) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        var nursing: AnyObject! = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Nursing", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

        //println("currentChild: \(currentChild?.description)")

        nursing.setValue(currentChild!, forKey: "child")
        if side == "left" {
            nursing.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "leftstarttime")
            nursing.setValue("active", forKey: "leftstate")
        }else{
            nursing.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "rightstarttime")
            nursing.setValue("active", forKey: "rightstate")
        }

        println("nursing: \(nursing.description)")
        var error:NSError?
        if managedObjectContext!.save(&error) != true {
            println("insert error: \(error!)")
            return
        }else{
            activeNursing = (nursing as! Nursing)
        }

    }
```

When I call this function the first time it is successful in saving a record, but if I call it a second time I get the following error:

```
insert error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo=0x17026e940 {NSValidationErrorKey=child, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject=<Baby_Master.Nursing: 0x1740ce310> (entity: Nursing; id: 0xd000000000080002 <x-coredata://29485885-9E6E-4BCA-8B4C-1617F191B7BC/Nursing/p2> ; data: {
    child = nil;
    completed = 1;
    leftduration = 0;
    leftstarttime = "2015-06-23 15:51:27 +0000";
    leftstate = ready;
    mood = nil;
    note = nil;
    rightduration = 0;
    rightstarttime = "2015-06-23 15:51:03 +0000";
    rightstate = ready;
    spitup = 0;
})}
```

What is strange is the data is is trying to save is not what I passed to the new "nursing" variable but is the previous saved record data.

When I print the new nursing var data I get this:

```
nursing: <Baby_Master.Nursing: 0x1740cdeb0> (entity: Nursing; id: 0x174226560 <x-coredata:///Nursing/t3C52AE5B-96E0-48F4-BF92-6185B00E2CC12> ; data: {
    child = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://29485885-9E6E-4BCA-8B4C-1617F191B7BC/Child/p2>";
    completed = 0;
    leftduration = 0;
    leftstarttime = nil;
    leftstate = ready;
    mood = nil;
    note = nil;
    rightduration = 0;
    rightstarttime = "2015-06-23 17:11:54 +0000";
    rightstate = active;
    spitup = 0;
})
```

You can see that the "nursing" variable that I'm trying to save contains the reference to the "child" data, which is not optional and is the reason I'm getting the error.

My question is why isn't the new "nursing" variable with the new data being used as opposed to the old data?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, the problem came down to a simple oversight on my part. It turns out I was missing @NSManaged var nursings: NSSet! in my Child model class.

Duh!

The fixed model is:

```
class Child:NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var avatar:NSData!
    @NSManaged var birthdate:NSDate!
    @NSManaged var datecreated:NSDate!
    @NSManaged var datemodified:NSDate!
    @NSManaged var bloodtype:NSString!
    @NSManaged var eyecolor:String
    @NSManaged var firstname:String!
    @NSManaged var gender:String!
    @NSManaged var haircolor:String!
    @NSManaged var baths:NSSet!
    @NSManaged var nursings: NSSet!
    @NSManaged var diapers: NSSet!
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else who runs across this issue.